# How do I calibrate Laptop screen in Ubuntu 22.04 OR How do I know what my current Color profile is?

Tags: laptop, hp, colors, 22.04, monitor-calibration

I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS on an HP Laptop. In `Settings`, there is a section for `Colors` under which my `Laptop Screen` is `Not calibrated` and when I try to `Calibrate` it, the button is greyed out, as shown in the picture.

[image: Screenshot showing Laptop Screen Not Calibrated, and Calibrate button being greyed out]

A bit of searching shows that you need something else to actually know what the color profile is, and Add that profile.

However, I clearly remember checking out the Settings when I first installed the OS, and at that time, I remember clearly that the Laptop Screen had a profile. And that was after I changed the theme and Night Light, so it's not those things that are affecting it.
In addition, I have the Bootable USB with Ubuntu 22.04 LTS, and when I did 'Try Ubuntu,' sure enough, the Laptop Screen was already calibrated with the profile being `Default - HP Laptop 15g-br0xx`.
But even there, the `View Details` button was greyed out, and there isn't such a profile as that in the list on my installed OS.

My question is: is there a command to know exactly what color profile is the so called 'Default'? And is there a way to kind of auto detect that on my installed OS? I can, of course, reinstall, but if there's a way to do this without reinstalling, I'd prefer that.

Answer (score 0):

If there is a profile for your screen on the install media, you may well copy it from there; look for `.icc` or `.icm` files to match your display.

Now, to **create** one of those files you need a screen calibrator;
to actually calibrate - you need to know is which one calibrator would be "compatible with Linux" (which currently is unknown to me).

Calibrator examples, 2022: https://www.creativebloq.com/features/best-monitor-calibrator

The Datacolor Spyder in earlier versions (3, 4) was not possible to use at the time when I jumped ship on Windows (a few years back).

The "Calibrate" button will most certainly be enabled if such hardware is present, connected to your computer.

With a profile in place; you need the knowledge to handle your image editing accordingly.

Note that a calibrated display requires software to adapt to it (and adjust the images to display accordingly); one such is "GIMP" - if you learn to actually use profiles in a meaningful way.

This "handling" was something I spent quite some time to get to grips with; googling all the time, trying out things, to understand.
*If you wish to get this knowledge; try to find someone to show you.*

**More:**
In general; an INPUT profile will tell how e.g. a scanner behaves w.r.t color.

The DISPLAY profile will be similar to a printer profile below; i.e. telling which colors to use for closest match to your image colors.

An output profile; e.g. for a **printer and paper *combination*** tells which colors are POSSIBLE to print; which then e.g. GIMP may adjust your image into.

*If you ponder a bit on the above, you realize that all here leads to estimations, closest match - **NOT a perfect image**.*

**In the end, I'd say this:**
Color profiles are for those who wishes to create "true color" images - e.g. in PRINT.
Calibration is a TOOL in that type of work.

Oh... one more thing: A laptop display has at least historically been 6 bit only - i.e. not capable of displaying the image stored in a JPG file (which is 8 bits per R,G,B).
And: a JPG cannot handle (store) soft / smooth gradients, e.g. Sunset images may have visible banding.

---

*No bragging zone; Some of the images here; http://www.flickr.com/arkane are the result of me dabbling with Nikon cameras, editing with Photoshop and later Darktable - on a calibrated 10 bit display (10 bit per R,G,B), calibrating and printing on an Epson A2 Deskjet in large formats (more than one print covering several sheets of paper).*

*For best possible view: display this image https://www.flickr.com/photos/arkane/13806525645/ and adjust so that you see as many hues as possible.*

---

A good place to start reading about details (technical!), as it seems at a first glance:
https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/ICC_profiles

Comment: I reinstalled the OS, and now it shows as Calibrated. In your answer you mentioned to look for `.icm` or `.icc` files. Can you please clarify where I could find them? As in, which folder should I search in? I do not know what 'uncalibrated' it on the last install, but what are some things that can do so, so I can avoid them?

Comment: `sudo apt install mlocate && sudo updatedb && locate .icm` - might reveal it, I have no recollection of poking about in any specific folder. This is most likely the only "future-proof" way to find them. Do `locate .icc` aftewards to find any of those.

Comment: Note: sRGB is the most "web-safe" OUTPUT profile.