# Xubuntu 22.04 missing Display profiles

Tags: xubuntu, 22.04, display-manager

After a fresh Xubuntu 22.04, I'm unable to see or select Display Profiles (see image below). I'm using VirtualBox 6.1.6.

Any ideas on how to make it work? Thanks!

[image: Xubuntu 22.04 missing Display profiles]

Comment: It's likely a xfce general issue https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/602725/no-display-profiles-available-with-xfce4

Comment: You simply need to calibrate your display; this process creates a valid profile. See my answer here https://askubuntu.com/a/1404585/289138 for some level of detail.